# R loading in specific part of a dataset

Tags: r, list, dataframe, import

I used to load in my data into individual dataframes using the following code:

```
filenames = list.files(path=path, pattern=".txt") #maakt een vector 'filenames' met alle .txt files in de betreffende folder

## 2.2 Data inladen

colnamesfull = c("time","v","a","t1","t2","t3","t4","t5","t6","t7","t8")
for(i in filenames){
  filepath = file.path(path, paste(i, sep=""))
  assign(i, read.table(filepath,
                       skip= 20, 
                       col.names= colnamesfull, 
                       sep=","))}
```

I have by now figured out that loading these txt files directly into a list is way more effective, and have managed to do so with the following code:

```
filenames = list.files(path=path, pattern=".txt")
fn <- paste(path,filenames,sep="/")
mylist <- lapply(fn, read.table, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

However, I still want to do the modifications that I did with my previous method. namely:

- Removing the first 20 rows, which are text and not data
- Adding names to the columns as in colnamesfull

How do I do this? I have tried filling in the read.table within lapply, but that doesn't work.

The dataframes look like this when loaded into mylist:

```
c("description=Peilopzet_Twentekanaal", "reference_heater_voltage=11", 
"pulsetime=25.0", "measuretime=300", "filebasename=SD07_TWK_", 
"measureinterval=1800", "nosleep=0", "sampletime=1", "IP=?.?.?.?", 
"Battery=15.86V", "Firmware=91", "Bootreason=BootReason(poweron=False,", 
"user=False,", "rtc=True,", "timeout=False)", "Sensorfirmware=Rev:", 
"98", "Datetime=2019-08-22", "00:30:04", "DatetimeFromNTP=True", 
"Heatervoltage=15.860000000000001", "Heaterduty=0.4810375781785452", 
"Compass=-317", "639", "42", "ApplicationVersion=trunk-r47", 
"ApplicationDate=2017-12-06", "11:17:33", "+0100", "2.0,14.820,1.500,14.61,14.63,14.63,14.65,14.65,14.63,14.64,14.60", 
"3.9,14.804,1.476,14.61,14.62,14.63,14.65,14.65,14.63,14.64,14.60", 
"5.8,14.820,1.500,14.61,14.62,14.63,14.65,14.65,14.63,14.64,14.60"
)
```

I have managed to use skip, but this doesn't work as I can't get col.names to work afterwards. the dataset looks like this with skip used as follows:

```
filenames = list.files(path=path, pattern=".txt")
fn <- paste(path,filenames,sep="/")
mylist <- lapply(fn, read.table, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, skip=21)
```

an image of the dataset

```
> mylist[[1]]
                                                                    V1
1     2.0,14.820,1.500,14.61,14.63,14.63,14.65,14.65,14.63,14.64,14.60
2     3.9,14.804,1.476,14.61,14.62,14.63,14.65,14.65,14.63,14.64,14.60
3     5.8,14.820,1.500,14.61,14.62,14.63,14.65,14.65,14.63,14.64,14.60
```

When I put the dataset through dput() the V1 doesn't show up

```
> dput(test[0:5,])
c("2.0,14.808,1.478,14.63,14.64,14.65,14.66,14.67,14.65,14.65,14.62", 
"3.9,14.808,1.472,14.63,14.64,14.65,14.66,14.67,14.65,14.65,14.62", 
"5.9,14.816,1.491,14.63,14.64,14.65,14.66,14.67,14.65,14.65,14.62", 
"7.8,14.816,1.490,14.63,14.64,14.65,14.66,14.67,14.65,14.65,14.62", 
"9.7,14.808,1.470,14.62,14.64,14.65,14.66,14.67,14.65,14.65,14.62"
```

How do i get rid of the 'V1' that is messing it all up?

Comment: `mylist <- lapply(fn, read.table, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, skip= 20, col.names= colnamesfull, sep=",")`?

Comment: Yes that worked! Thank you so much! 
Should have tried adding that myself XD

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Roland:

```
mylist <- lapply(fn, read.table, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, skip= 20, col.names= colnamesfull, sep=",")
```